# ERROR: The method onCreate(Bundle) in the type alertFunction is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: android, sms

I'm a beginner and i'm getting that error on my Main Activity file. I hope you can help me on my problem. I'm trying to make a Reminder Message sender for my project i really don't know how to correct the errors because i'm a newbie.

MainActivity codes:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Dialog;


public class MainActivity extends Activity

{
Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
timeAndDatePicker timeClass = new timeAndDatePicker();
alertFunction alertClass = new alertFunction();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {                
       String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
       String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
       if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
           sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
       else
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
               "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       timeClass.setCurrentDateOnView();
       timeClass.addListenerOnButton();
       alertClass.onCreate(); <<---- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.

   }


 private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {
   String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
   String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

   PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

   PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

   // ---when the SMS has been sent---
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           switch (getResultCode()) {
               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
           }
       }
   }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

   // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           switch (getResultCode()) {
               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
           }
       }
   }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

   SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}

});
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `onCreate()` explicitely. Once you declare an instance of a class, if it has the `onCreate()` class, it will be automatically called at the appropiate time.

If you override that class, always be sure to declare the `@Override` statement above it, this will make sure you're overriding the correct function because if you don't, and you don't specify the correct parameters that the former method has, it will not be called and you'll think it does.

Also, it's a good idea to call `super.onCreate(savedInstance)` as the first line of your overriden method.

**---- EDIT ----**

As said above, `onCreate()` is called on the object creation, i.e., when you declare:  `alertFunction alertClass = new alertFunction();`.

If this is something you want to call several times, put the content in a public function inside your class and call it from `onCreate()` and from the outside when needed. For instance:

```
public void myFunction() {
  // Put here the current code of onCreate()
  ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance);
  myFunction();
}
```

And then if you need to call it again from outside your class, do the following:

```
alertClass.myFunction();
```

Comment: what code should i use for alertClass instead then?