# I am using android studio 8.0

Tags: android

I am using android studio 8.0. and I made a simple activity to go to another activity here are these errors are shown

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask]

Comment: There is no such thing as android studio 8.0

Comment: How would you even think that "I am using android studio 8.0" is a proper title...

Comment: Please paste complete code of this class

Comment: Where did you get that 8.0 version? 3.0 is the latest version of android studio.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call onCreate() explicitely. Once you declare an instance of a class, if it has the  onCreate() class, it will be automatically called at the appropiate time.

If you override that class, always be sure to declare the @Override statement above it, this will make sure you're overriding the correct function because if you don't, and you don't specify the correct parameters that the former method has, it will not be called and you'll think it does.

Also, it's a good idea to call super.onCreate(savedInstance) as the first line of your overriden method.

---- EDIT ----

As said above, onCreate() is called on the object creation, i.e., when you declare: alertFunction alertClass = new alertFunction();.

If this is something you want to call several times, put the content in a public function inside your class and call it from onCreate() and from the outside when needed. For instance:

```
public void myFunction() {
  // Put here the current code of onCreate()
  ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance);
  myFunction();
}
```

And then if you need to call it again from outside your class, do the following:

```
alertClass.myFunction();
```

Source: [ERROR: The method onCreate(Bundle) in the type alertFunction is not applicable for the arguments ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372409/error-the-method-oncreatebundle-in-the-type-alertfunction-is-not-applicable-f)

By the way, there is no Android Studio 8.0. Check out this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html

Hope this helps! Good luck!